# Using office.js API to insert Excel into a Word document

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

Word allows a user to copy/paste a range of cells directly into a document and they get embedded into the document as a new Excel file which can be opened for editing directly from Word.

The office.js API allows for various things to be inserted into a Word document such as HTML, Image, etc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#insertHtml_html__insertLocationString_

Is there a way to insert an Excel worksheet or a range of cells using the office.js API?

Answer (score 0):

Office.js does not support this at the present time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is this a planned future functionality?